# Connect the Remix Ethereum IDE to localhost

Tags: bash, ethereum, blockchain, remix

I would like to connect Remix - Ethereum IDE (https://remix.ethereum.org) to localhost.

I followed the instructions https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remixd.html#update-to-the-latest-remixd:

1. I installed remix daemon `npm install -g @remix-project/remixd` using npm.
2. I created folder `mkdir ~/shared_project`.
3. I gave read/write privilege to this folder `chmod u+rw shared_project` for my local user.
4. I started remix daemon `sudo remixd -s ~/shared_project --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`.

The problem is that when I would like to connect Remix IDE in a browser to localhost I can see the popup window with the error message `Cannot connect to the remixd daemon. Please make sure you have the remixd running in the background.`.

I tried to reboot daemon:

1. `ps -ef | grep remixd`
2. `sudo kill 1007`
3. `sudo remixd -s ~/shared_project --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`.

I tried to reinstall the daemon:

1. `sudo npm uninstall -g @remix-project/remixd`
2. `sudo npm install -g @remix-project/remixd`

I tried to reopen the remix browser IDE

However I can see this error message still.

I expect that I can connect Remix IDE in a browser to localhost.

p.s. I use MacOs Monterey Version 12.2 and Safari browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Google Chrome browser, you can connect the Remix Ethereum IDE to localhost with no issues.

If you use Safari browser, you need to clear Safari cache. Only after that you would be able to connect the Remix Ethereum IDE to localhost with no issues.

P.s. May be there are other things else which can help to resolve the issue.

Comment: I was using Brave and that failed to connect. But Chrome worked. I would have thought the common Chromium would have been enough.